# When to use て forms with commas?

Tags: て-form, punctuation

Consider two variants of a sentence with a comma:

1. 雨が**降って**、傘を持ってきてよかった。
2. 雨が**降った**、傘を持ってきてよかった。

I've seen that (2) is grammatical in Japanese (as opposed to English, where it would be considered a "run-on" sentence). Do both variants mean the same thing ("It was raining, so I was glad I bought my umbrella")? If not, what is the difference between them, and in general when should one use the て-form with commas?

My guess is that (1) has more of a cause and effect relationship ("It was raining, and *then*, because of that, I brought an umbrella and was glad"). Then I suppose (2) is more disjointed, and could mean ("It was raining, and I happened to have an umbrella, so I was glad")?

Comment: Neither is particularly natural. 1 is grammatical; 2 is orthographically anomalous in using dictionary form before comma. Consider 空に雲が広がって、雨が降り始めた. This is like (ordinary) *Clouds spread over the sky, **and** it started to rain* while ・・・た、雨が・・・ is like *Clouds spread over the sky, it started to rain* without *and*.

Comment: @sundowner: So in general, only the て form should ever precede a comma?

Comment: Neither suggests a cause and effect relationship between raining and bringing an umbrella.

Comment: @George [連用形]{れにょうけい}/Continuative form, similarly to *te*-form, can be used for conjoining of clauses, and it can be followed by comma.

Comment: If a relative clause is paused by a comma, dictionary form+comma is naturally used. 彼が持っていた、古い本。= an old book which he was carrying.

Comment: Where have you seen that sentence 2 style is grammatical? Do you mean you've just encountered it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which is the intended meaning of your Sentence (1)?

- **A**: It was actually raining when I went out, so I took an umbrella. It ended up being useful in some other way (say, as a photography reflector or a weapon).
- **B**: I brought an umbrella when I went out because I anticipated that it might rain. It did end up raining, so the umbrella was indeed useful.

If **A** is the intended meaning, your Sentence (1) is correct. If **B** is the intended meaning, Sentence (1) is awfully unnatural because of the limitation described in the last part of [this article](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html).

> In this sentence pattern, Sentence 1 and Sentence 2 are sequential events. In other words, Sentence 1 takes place first and Sentence 2 takes place after that.
>
> 1. 明日試験があって、今日準備しなければなりません。 X

Therefore, when you say 雨が降っ**て**傘を持ってき**て**よかった, "雨が降った" → "傘を持ってきた" → "よかった" must happen in this sequence. **A** satisfies this, but **B** doesn't. If **B** is what you mean, you must say "(本当に)雨が降った**ので**、(あらかじめ)傘を持ってきてよかった".

---

As for Sentence (2), it's just two independent sentences somehow joined with a comma instead of a period. While such a technique may be deliberately employed to convey halting thoughts in monologues or similar contexts, it's simply incorrect as standard Japanese.

Comment: The fact that (1) means A is really tricky and unexpected! But your answer led me to explore [causality nuances among て, から, and ので](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/101017/does-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-any-retain-subjective-reason-for-action-meaning-from-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89),  and their differences remind me a lot of Japanese conditionals (から/ので reminds me of ~たら action conditionals, while て reminds me of と or ~えば conditionals). Not sure if that makes any sense :)